# While pod install & update from Jenkins getting Error

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cocoapods

```
[iOSTestBuild] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/7h/c_dd36k5627bbs6pbhd4zglw0000gn/T/jenkins10828028391649479003.sh
+ /opt/homebrew/bin/pod install --repo update
    [33mWARNING: CocoaPods requires your terminal to be using UTF-8 encoding.
    Consider adding the following to ~/.profile:

    export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    [0m
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:118:in `block in which!': [31m[!] Unable to locate the executable `git`[0m (Pod::Informative)
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:117:in `which!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:143:in `capture_command'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:126:in `git_version'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:140:in `verify_minimum_git_version!'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:49:in `run'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
    from /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

On my Mac, when I run the same command it works, only through Jenkins when I run the command it gives me this error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the machine on which you are running jenkins is unable to locate git executable, you can try following commands to troubleshoot it:

1. Check if git is there on the machine running jenkins using: `git --version`
2. If git is installed, ensure the executable is in the system path by running `echo $PATH`, if its not there set it.
3. Try `pod install` command outside of Jenkins and if it works then try specifying the full path to the git executable in the Jenkins build script.
   Alternatively, you can add the path to the git executable directly to the PATH environment variable in the Jenkins configuration

Answer (score 0):

If it work through shell, but not on Jenkins, that means the environment/user is different.

On Jenkins, add to your job commands to see what your user and environment are, as well as where it finds `git`.

```
id -a
env
which git
```

That way, you will see what you need to add to your user environment in order to get Git in your `$PATH`, like your Jenkins agent (assuming it is running on your Mac) is able to do.

Comment: can you chek the question the case is vise versa

Comment: @DropAndTrap the idea remains the same: compare the two environment settings, to get a clue as to why it is working in one and not in the other.